# Why is $\int_1^4 (2x+2)\, dx \le \int_1^4 (3x+1)\, dx$?

Tags: calculus

My teacher said to prove that

$$\int\limits_{[1,4]}(2x+2)\, dx \le \int\limits_{[1,4]}(3x+1)\, dx.$$

$$2x+1\le 2x+x,$$
so
$$2x+2\le 2x+x+1.$$
But how do we know that $2x+1\le2x+x$?

And as I know if we add something on the left side we should add it also on the right side, right?

Comment: If you add different values to each side of *an equality*, then you will get an *inequality*.

Answer (score 11):

The inequality $2x + 1 \leq 2x + x$ is equivalent to the inequality $1 \leq x$, which is true on the interval $[1,4]$ we are looking at.